# ColdFusion 10 directoryCreate and spreadsheetWrite functions including full directory path with forward slashes as part of single folder name on a mac

Tags: macos, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am using ColdFusion 10 on a Windows machine. I am creating a directory for storing generated excel reports using directoryCreate() and spreadsheetWrite() cfscript functions. It works fine on Windows.

I have a work colleague who is developing on a mac with OS X mavericks. When the code is executed on his machine, one of two things happens. Either the file includes the full path name in the actual file name (e.g. "/folder/anotherfolder/thefile.xls" as single file name) and is placed in the root of the web project folder, or a single folder is created with the forward slashes as part of the folder name (e.g. "/folder/anotherfolder/" as single folder name).

Here are a couple of examples that I have tried for creating the initial root folder structure:

```
request.rootPath = ExpandPath("*.*");
request.rootDirectory = GetDirectoryFromPath(request.rootPath);
```

OR

```
request.rootPath = ExpandPath("./");
request.rootDirectory = GetDirectoryFromPath(request.rootPath);
```

OR

```
request.rootPath = ExpandPath("/");
request.rootDirectory = GetDirectoryFromPath(request.rootPath);
```

I then use request.rootDirectory in the directoryCreate() function, e.g.:

```
// within my fw/1 cfc...
rc.userReportPath = "#request.rootDirectory#folder\anotherfolder\";
if (!directoryExists(rc.userReportPath)) {
    directoryCreate(rc.userReportPath);
}
```

And then create the spreadsheet file (where rc.excelFileName is my dynamic file name based on the logged in user:

```
spreadsheetWrite(rc.s, "#rc.userReportPath##rc.excelFileName#", true);
```

The only possible clue I've found so far is something to do with forward slashes being unicode characters that are only being displayed as forward slashes, not actual forward slashes for folder path creation (I hope that makes sense). Although, it may have nothing to do with this. The production environment is on a Windows environment so this isn't a major issue going forward, but being a bit obsessive, I'd really like to know what's really causing this behaviour so that I can avoid it in future.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me figure this one out :)

Comment: What is the actual value of the path ie `#rc.userReportPath##rc.excelFileName#`? Is it actually valid for OSX? It looks like windows style separators are used `\`? Try using `/` instead, which is [valid on windows or mac](http://corfield.org/entry/Backslash_is_NOT_a_path_separator).

Comment: Thanks Leigh, I replaced `request.rootPath = ExpandPath("*.*")` with `request.rootPath = ReplaceNoCase(ExpandPath("*.*"),'\','/','all')` and it worked perfectly. If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Thanks for the assist. Hopefully I won't make that mistake again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From comments ...)

What is the actual value of the path ie `#rc.userReportPath##rc.excelFileName#`? Is it actually valid for OSX? It looks like windows style separators are being used ie `\`.

Try using `/` instead, which is [valid for both windows and mac](http://corfield.org/entry/Backslash_is_NOT_a_path_separator).